# Caption alignment

Tags: captions, line-breaking, positioning

For my master degree thesis I'm using a quite complicated latex template.

The relevant part of the template is here: http://pastie.org/1728702

Probably this wasn't a good idea since I cannot understand how to put the text in the captions just below the "Figure #".
The text in the caption is aligned as in the figure in this page:

[image]

I'm using the *scrbook* class. I tried to remove the caption package but nothing changed.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing that the KOMA-Script document classes format their captions "hanging", i.e. if it will not fit into a single line the caption will continue right beside "Figure #". See KOMA-Script guide for details and how to change this. (And the caption package will respect that setting, see caption package documentation, section "KOMA-Script" for details.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already loading the caption package you could try:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{%
  labelsep=newline,
  format=plain,
  indention=0pt
}
```